# Arent closures supose to allocate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have always worked from the standpoint that closures create allocation and should be avoided from critical code, is this standpoint obsolete?

[image]

```cs
using System;

public class Foo
{
    private Random rand = new Random();

    private static int Get(Func<int> factory)
    {
        return factory() + 1;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foobar");

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        float foo = 1f;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            foo += DoTestRun();
        }
    }

    private float DoTestRun()
    {
        var j = rand.Next(0, 100);
        return Get(() => j + 5);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new Foo().Test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they do allocate; here's the top of the allocation debugger in devenv:

```
Name    Total (Allocations) Total Size (Bytes)
 + System.Func`1    100002  6400128
| + [Native]    100002  6400128
|| + Program::Main  100002  6400128
||| + Foo::Test 100002  6400128
|||| - Foo::DoTestRun   51190   3276160
|||| - Foo::DoTestRun   48810   3123840
|||| - System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)  2   128
 + Foo.<>c__DisplayClass3_0 100000  2400000
| + [Native]    100000  2400000
|| + Program::Main  100000  2400000
||| + Foo::Test 100000  2400000
|||| - Foo::DoTestRun   51190   1228560
|||| - Foo::DoTestRun   48810   1171440
```

These are the delegates and the capture context instances from `Get(() => j + 5)`. So yes, it allocates. Whether this is catastrophic to your scenario: depends a lot on your scenario.

Comment: @Anders visual studio => Debug => Performance Profiler... => .NET Object Allocation Tracking

Comment: @Anders just a guess, but presumably because you're using a snapshot profiler, and your thing happens too quickly to be seen in a snapshot?